# Issue in Primefaces editor

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces' editor gives the following java script error on focus if it already has some data in it :

```
unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference in editor.js
```

Prime faces version : 5.1
IE : 10
It works fine with Compatibility & Document mode as 9.

Please suggest the reason & fix for it.

Comment: Tried a newer version of PF?

Comment: We migrated to Primefaces 5.1 from 4.0 & from IE 9 to 10 simultaneously. We do not have the earlier configurations now. So, not sure issue is with IE or with primefaces 5.1. Please suggest.

Comment: See my suggestion above (and check releasenotes,  issuelists,  blogs etc)

Comment: It is not working with 5.2 as well.